# side menu left in category and subcategory

Tags: category, menu, submenu

In this web site:
http://shop.caffemauro.com/it/caffe

the left menu (where the title is) "CAFFE"

**is the same in all subcategory**

http://shop.caffemauro.com/it/caffe/caffe-casa

http://shop.caffemauro.com/it/caffe/caffe-bar

http://shop.caffemauro.com/it/caffe/cialde-in-carta

etc...

How make it?

Usually the left menu there is only in category not subcategory.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove from layered navigation tou can edit app/design/frontend/template/package/layout/catalog.xml

and find:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
```

and replace with:

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
        </block>
```

Comment: i would like to add the side menu left static in all category and subcategory